# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when running cordova build

Tags: cordova

Using Cordova for the first time and this one has stumped me right from the beginning. When running "cordova build" on the default project that's set up when you run cordova create... I'm getting the following error:

```
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jen/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
studio
(node:1951) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]
(node:1951) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 and Cordova at 8.0.0. I've probably missed something during installation but I can't find what it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem on macOS High Sierra.

```
(node:1951) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]
(node:1951) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is just a warning.
Firstly remove your previous version of jdk

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
sudo rm -rf jdk1.8.0_101.jdk
```

Download the dmg from :
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<your version>/Contents/Home
```

If further error occurs try :

```
brew install gradle
```

Hope this resolves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Have the same problem (though Windows10). See here: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13740
and here:
https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/pull/440
Seems a known but unresolved issue.

BUT - later I found that this error comes only when something else is wrong (e.g. missing SDK or something). Once I got EVERYTHING correct (it wasn't easy) this error also disappeared. So - I think it's only a symptom.